# Getting an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to display `Node.JS` `API's` data using `React` and getting this error. The data is stored using `MongoDB`. It doesn't give out error while displaying the upvotes. It only gives error while printing out the comments.

This is the data that I am trying to print. Mainly I am trying to print the comments. I am not sure what mistake I am doing here while printing the data.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed8b795e08db8286109e8b0"),
        "name" : "learn-react",
        "upvotes" : 46,
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "user" : "Tom",
                        "text" : "True"
                },
                {
                        "user" : "Tom",
                        "text" : "True"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed8b795e08db8286109e8b1"),
        "name" : "learn-node",
        "upvotes" : 35,
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "user" : "Levy",
                        "text" : "Thanks"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed8b795e08db8286109e8b2"),
        "name" : "learn-cv",
        "upvotes" : 6,
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "user" : "Harry",
                        "text" : "Thanks for the info"
                },
                {
                        "user" : "Levy",
                        "text" : "Thanks"
                }
        ]
}
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import articles from "./Content";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ArticleList from "../components/ArticleList";
import CommentsList from "../components/CommentsList";

const Articles = ({ match }) => {
  const name = match.params.name;

  const [articleInfo, setArticleInfo] = useState([]);
  //fetching url name/handle from the articles Route path

  useEffect(() => {
    let headers = new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
    });
    fetch(`/api/articles/${name}`, headers)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setArticleInfo(result);
          console.log("ex");
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  });

  //Return name if url path matches the name of the article
  const foundArticle = articles.find((article) => article.name === name);
  //display articles except the current one
  const otherArticles = articles.filter((article) => article.name !== name);
  /*const displayComments=articleInfo.comments.map((item, i) =>{
    const {user, text} =item;
    return(
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li key={i}>{user}</li>
          <li>{text}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  })*/
  return (
    <div>
      {foundArticle ? (
        <div>
          <p>Total likes: {articleInfo.upvotes}</p>

          <h2>{foundArticle.title}</h2>
          <p>{foundArticle.content}</p>

          <CommentsList comments={articleInfo.comments}/>
          <Link className="btn" to="/articles-all">
            All blog
          </Link>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <h4>Not found</h4>
      )}
      <ArticleList articles={otherArticles} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Articles;

import React from 'react'

 const CommentsList = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.comments.map((item,i)=>{
               return <p>{item.user}</p>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
export default CommentsList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using logical `&&` operator for conditional rendering:

```
const CommentsList = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            //this line tries to access props before they are passed
            //{props.comments.map((item,i)=>{
            //make sure it exists before trying to map it 
            {props.comments && props.comments.map((item,i)=>{
               return <p>{item.user}</p>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine. However, I am not sure why did it solve the issue. I know this would check if the comments is true and then only it would map it. But how did it solve?

Comment: Im by no means expert, so take it with a grain of salt. As i understand it, react, through props pass pointers to values, not actual values. So with initial render those pointers are mapped but since you are fetching data from external source (API) those pointers refer to value which is not defined yet. After you receive data, value is declared and component can read it. Hope that clarifies it a bit